Solving $6\cdot 2^{t+4}=3\cdot 4^{t−9}$
How would you work out the value of $t$?
$$6\cdot 2^{t+4}=3\cdot 4^{t−9}$$
I understand the basic law of indices but can't wrap my head around this.
So I understand that 4 can be rewritten as 2^2 making it
$$6\cdot 2^{t+4}=3\cdot 2^{2^{t−9}}$$
$$6\cdot 2^{t+4}=3\cdot 2^{2t-18}$$
I know that I have to make the base number the same, so that I can isolate the term with $t$ in it but I don't know how to get to that step.

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Note that $6\cdot2^{t+4}=3\cdot2^{t+5}$

Just divide both sides by $3$.  then you get $2\cdot 2^{t+4} = 4^{t-9}$.  Can you take it from there.  (Keep in mind that $a^b \cdot a^c = a^{b+c}$ and $(a^k)^d = a^{kd}$.  (You have a typo where yous used the caret symbol in your second equation to mean multiplication, btw)

The absolute worst way you can do this if you really don't see anything (such as both sides have a common factor of $3$) is to take the $\log_2{}$ of both side.  $\log_2 6\cdot 2^{t+4} =\log_2 6 + \log_2 2^{t+4} = \log_2 6 + (t+4)$ and $\log_2 3\cdot 4^{t-9} = \log_2 3 + \log_2 4^{t-9}=\log_2 3 + (t-9)\log_2 4 = \log_2 3 + 2(t-9)$.  Now you need to compare $\log_2 6$ to $\log_2 3$ and we note $\log_2 6= \log_2 2\cdot 3 = \log_2 2 + \log_3 2 = 1 + \log_32$ so we have $\log_2 3 + 1 + (t+4) = \log_2 3 + 2(t-9)$ and that's easy to solve.  Course that's the HARD way...

Notice that  $6=2×3.$
You can cancel that 3 with the 3 on the right side leaving
$$2×2^{t+ 4}= 2^{2t-18}$$
$$2^{t+ 4+ 1}= 2^{t+ 5}= 2^{2t- 18}.$$
So $t+ 5= 2t-18$
$$t= 18+ 5= 23.$$

You must have meant $6=2\cdot3$ when you typed $6=23$!

And a third method, generally useful, even when the bases are different.  Strategy: remove addends from the variable in the exponent.  Get everything with that variable in an exponent on the left side of the equation.
\begin{align*}
6 \cdot 2^{t+4} &= 3 \cdot 4^{t-9}  \\
6 \cdot 2^t \cdot 2^4 &= 3 \cdot 4^t \cdot 4^{-9}  \\
2^t \cdot 4^{-t}&= \frac{1}{6} \cdot 3 \cdot 4^{-9} \cdot 2^{-4}  \\
\left(\frac{2}{4}\right)^{t} &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot 4^{-9} \cdot 2^{-4}  \\
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{t} &= 2^{-1} \cdot 2^{-18} \cdot 2^{-4}  \\
2^{-t} &= 2^{-23}  \text{, so }  \\
    t &= 23  \text{.}
\end{align*}
I say "general" above because even if we didn't have the same base on both sides, say
$$ \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^t = 3^{-23}  \text{, }  $$
we can still finish by just taking logarithms
$$  t = -23 \log_{1/2}(3) = 23 \log_{2}(3) \text{.}  $$

Heh, heh... not the easiest but if you know logs you don't have to think.  Just do.
$6\cdot 2^{t+4} = 3\cdot 4^{t-9}$
$\log (6\cdot 2^{t+4}) = \log (3\cdot 4^{t-9})$
$\log 6 + (t+4)\log 2 = \log 3 + (t-9)\log 4$
$\log 3\cdot 2 + (t+4)\log 2 = \log 3 + (t-9) \log 2^2$
$\log 3 + \log 2 +(t+4)\log 2 = \log 3 + 2(t-9)\log 2$
$\require{cancel} $ $\cancel{\log 3} + \log 2(1 + (t+4)) = \cancel{\log 3} + 2(t-9)\log 2$
$\frac {\log 2 (t+5)}{\log 2} = \frac {2(t-9)\log 2}{\log 2}$
$\frac {\cancel\log 2 (t+5)}{\cancel\log 2} = \frac {2(t-9)\cancel\log 2}{\cancel\log 2}$
$t+5 = 2(t-9)$
$t+ 5 = 2t -18$
$t-t + 5 + 18 = 2t-t -18 + 18$
$23 = t$.
Now... you may be asking "log of what base?" and the answer is ... It doesn't matter!
But.... this isn't the easiest way to do it

$$6×2^{t+4}=3×4^{t-9}$$or
$$3×2^1×2^{t+4}=3×(2^2)^{t-9}$$
or
$$2^{t+5}=2^{2t-18}$$
Thus taking $\log$ on both sides,
$$t+5=2t-18$$or$$23=t$$

Not a direct answer, but you made an interesting mistake in the question, that is part of learning manipulation of exponents:
$$6⋅2^{t+4}=3⋅2^{2^{t−9}}$$
So you were implying $4^{t-9} = 2^{2^{t-9}}$
That is incorrect, replacing $4$ with $2^2$ should make $(2^2)^{t-9}$
so what you want to write is
$$6⋅2^{t+4}=3⋅(2^2)^{t−9}$$
It has to do with the priority of operations, $3^{3^2}$ actually means $3^{(3^2)} = 3^{9} = 19683$ while $(3^3)^2 = 9^2 = 81$.
You corrected the error on the next line, with an similar error:
you can use $(3^3)^2 = 3^{3 \times 2} = 3^6 = 81$ but you cannot use $3^{3^2} = 3^{3 \times 2}$.
You corrected the error so it seems that you understand the meaning, but it is important to use the correct notation. $2^{2^{t-9}}$ is a huge number and not the one you want to use.
